# get non-null systemService

Tags: android, null, system-services

Every time I'm assigning getSystemService to some variable I have to check later if it is null, eg.

```
LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (mLocationManager != null) {...}
```

Is there any way to make it non null for sure?

Comment: One way to do that is by writing `getSystemService()` in such a way that it never returns a null object (i.e. throwing if it cannot create one).  Of course, you would then have to wrap the call in a `catch` block.  If you don't own the `getSystemService` code, then there's nothing more you can do.

Comment: So overall, I'd say that you're probably already doing the best you can.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen location manager come back null.  Did you add permissions?

Comment: Ofc I did, and it never came as null to me, but it is just a possibility, android studio is warning me about it so I was wandering... On the other hand this one `NotificationManager mNotificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);` did crash on me once after hundresds/thousands of launches